ESP32 C3 Super Mini resets after reading serial line with C#
I would like to read the serial data with a C# Windows Forms Application. The data is send with an ESP32 C3 Super Mini. When I use the Serial Monitor from the Arduino IDE everything works fine.
If I'm reading the serial data with my C# Application (serialPort1.ReadLine(); or serialPort1.ReadExisting();) I will get the data only once and then the ESP resets with this reason: rst:0x15 (USB_UART_CHIP_RESET),boot:0xc (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
C# Code
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    lblState1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(ProcessData1));
}

private async void ProcessData1()
{
    //MessageBox.Show(serialPort1.ReadLine());
    MessageBox.Show(serialPort1.ReadExisting());
}

Arduino Code
unsigned long last_time = 0;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    // Print a heartbeat
    if (millis() > last_time + 2000)
    {
        Serial.println("Arduino is alive!!");
        last_time = millis();
    }
}

A few days ago the application worked fine. After I upload a new programm to the ESP32 I got this problem and can't fix it.
Edit
DtrEnable and RtsEnable are set to false.

You might want to avoid doing Serial I/O on the GUI thread. Other than that, there surely is mor tto tthe serial connection than that, right? Where do you open it? Why don't you catch exceptions?

@Fildor The C# code is about 430 lines long and everything else worked so I reduced the code to the lines above and still got the same error. I open the serial port with the Form Shown event. In my code i am catching exceptions but I don't get any exception an the C# side.

If the source code you provided is correct, then perhaps it's because a message box is being displayed? The processing is probably stopped there, waiting for the operator to act. Wouldn't it be better to add the content to be displayed using a text box control?

@kunif I used the message box for debugging only since i got the Problem. Even if I do nothing with the data and just call serialPort1.ReadExisting(); I got the same error.

If I use your example I get this error from the catch inside the void Read(): The connection is closed

In that case, why not try modifying the examples program that use the console in the Microsoft documentation? SerialPort Class For example, if you match the SerialPort.NewLine Property to the line terminator sent by the Arduino program, you can use the SerialPort.ReadLine Method as is.

@kunif I tried \r, \n, \r\n and the error is still "The connection is closed".
In my Windows Forms App the ReadLine get me only one line. That worked, but only once and then the ESP32 resets.

Have you tried using other terminal software that can use a serial port, such as PuTTY or TeraTerm? If you still get an error, perhaps the environment settings for the device driver to communicate with Arduino are incorrect?

@kunif TeraTerm and the Serial Monitor from the Arduino IDE can display the serial text. Putty can't open the serial port.

So you need to find out what the difference is between the programs that work and the ones that don't. Or, I found this program that uses .NET Framework 4.6.1, so you might want to check if it works using this. dalegambill/CsharpTerminal

@kunif Still get this error: rst:0x15 (USB_UART_CHIP_RESET),boot:0xf (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)

If you search for that error message, you will find many articles, so it may be necessary to search through them patiently. Cannot flash ESP32C3-SuperMini, ESP32 c3 wdt reboot fail (IDFGH-6051) #7734, ESP32-C3 Stuck waiting for download, Serial Monitoring esp32c3, ESP32-C3 SHA-256 comparison failed and no start

Now everything is working. I changed nothing in my C# programm and Arduino sketch. Thank you for your help @kunif

Problem got solved over night by just leaving the Arduino unpluged. Thanks to @kunif for your help.

It will be better to leave it as a comment. :)
